# How to change a complex menu to a simple textual menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

In my current wordpress theme, the following menu exists:

[image]

I would like it to be just a simple text based menu like this:

[image]

Here is the style.css for the menu:

```
/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#access {
    background: #ffffff; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#access a {

}
#access ul ul {

}
#access ul ul ul {

}
#access ul ul a {

}
#access a:focus {
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
}   
#access ul li:hover > ul {
}
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is the php code for the current menu. I don't know how to disassemble it without breaking it. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used. If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
```

Comment: If you are going to use an entirely different menu, you might as well consider using a different theme completely. Wordpress has a gallery at http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the containing HTML for the nav menu by modifying the array that you pass the function call. Read more: [wp_nav_menu#removing the navigation container](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Removing_the_Navigation_Container)